# How can I make multiple telebot handlers at once?

Tags: go, bots, telegram, telebot

how can i make multiple handlers at once using the telebot library in go?
i want to make a dialog between a user and a bot
i was able to find something similar using python, but it didnt help me

i want the user to be able to perform authorization in the service in stages, that is:

```
Bot: Enter the username.
User: username
Bot: Enter the password.
User: password
Bot: Authorization completed
```

how can i do this?

to communicate with the user, i use a Poller:

```
pref := tele.Settings{
   Token:   cfg.Telegram.TelegramToken,
   Poller:  &tele.LongPoller{Timeout: 10 * time.Second},
   OnError: a.OnBotError,
}
bot, err := tele.NewBot(pref)
```

i have a handler for authorization in some service:

```
a.bot.Handle(&btnAuth, func(c tele.Context) error {
}
```